# Two solidify modifiers not working well together

Tags: modifiers, transparency

I'm using two solidify modifiers because I want different thickness of the lines in different parts of the model. If I enable them separately they work well, but when I put both at the same time the model goes completely black.

[image]

Solidify 1

[image]

Solidify 2 (just for the face because I want the line thinner there)

[image]

Both enabled

Things you maybe want to know:

- The material i'm using is just a black emission with blackface culling activated and the blend mode in alpha clip so the transparent work, but with the two modifiers activated it is not working.
- Both modifiers have the normals flipped so the back face is outside. That way it should be transparent but the backface culling is not working with the two modifiers activated.
- English is not my first language sorry if there are mistakes.

Comment: Better to use one solidify modifier aimed at a vertex group. Then the thicknesses in the one modifier can be adjusted using the weights in the group.

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you! I didnt know I could change it with weight paint

Comment: .. or, perhaps you might want the precision of _setting_ the weights in Edit Mode. Either way.